# Add duplicate rows to output when there are values in specific columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to take a table that has three columns (num_id_1/2/3) with different versions of the same num_id and duplicate the rows such that each distinct num_id has its own row, with the rest of the data in the row duplicated. I only want to do this instances where there are multiple num_ids (so ignoring any blanks in the num_id_2 or 3 cols) so not to create a final output with blanks in the final num_id col:

For example:

```
  -----------------------------------------------------
  | Id | num_id_1   | num_id_2 | num_id_3 | other rows of data 
  ----------------------------------------------------
  | 1  | 11111      | 2222222  |33333333  | aaaa
  | 2  | 12345      |          |          | cccc
```

To:

```
   -----------------------------------------------------
  | Id | num_id     | other rows of data 
  ----------------------------------------------------
  | 1  | 11111      | aaaa
  | 1  | 2222222    | aaaa
  | 1  | 33333333   | aaaa
  | 2  | 12345      | cccc
```

How can I build the result?
This is in RedShift, which I am not very familiar with

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift, `union all` is probably the simplest approach:

```
select id, num_id_1 as num_id, other columns
from t
where num_id_1 is not null
union all
select id, num_id_2 as num_id, other columns
from t
where num_id_2 is not null
union all
select id, num_id_3 as num_id, other columns
from t
where num_id_3 is not null;
```